# Android studio can‘t run API level below 21

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

here is my `build.gradle`:

```
  android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
        aaptOptions {
            cruncherEnabled = false
            useNewCruncher = false

        }
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.prmgclient"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        }

    }



  dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
  }

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    }
```

My test machine is `android 4.4.2, API 19.Android studio 2.2.2.`
 I have tried to delete `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'`,but it did not work.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Why are you trying to delete app compact v7?

Comment: check if u have properly connected device to PC . if its VM then delete it and try creating a new one.

Comment: @Vicky I had did it ,but it stil notl work.I have find a new device with Android 5.1,API22,It worked！

Comment: @aa_oo I have changed SDK version

Comment: Minimum SDK version? @lovegod

Comment: yes,Min SDK version @aa_oo

Comment: I think you need to manage appcompat version which is compatible with 4.4.2. Because same problem I faced when trying to execute build on Lollipop & having lib of Marshmallow.